# 1 audio card with multiple digital outputs simultaneous use of digital outputs (pulseaudio)

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, hdmi, intel-nuc

I have an Intel NUC ([NUC5PPYH](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/nuc-pentium-brief.pdf)) running Lubuntu 19.10. Its TOSLINK optical port is connected to my receiver and the HDMI is connected to my TV.  On the NUC I can select all the outputs from PulseAudio and they work (select them via the configuration tab).   If I run `aplay -l` it shows that there is one card with multiple devices.

I use Spotify and Kodi,. I want Spotify's audio sent to the Optical output and Kodi to use the HDMI output for audio.

If I open Kodi, I can only select the output selected in the configure tab of PulseAudio. The output tab in PulseAudio also only lists the output selected in the configured tab.

The question is, how can I get it working such that I can select a different audio output in Kodi, so that sounds from Kodi output via HDMI and all others sounds go via the optical out?

Comment: Lubuntu and Ubuntu 19.04 are EOL (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  You need to upgrade first to a supported release of Ubuntu/Lubuntu (ie. 19.10)

Comment: @guiverc, I was mistaken, the NUC is running version 19.10 and edited the question